# Do I need to use a shader for OpenGL 3.3 Core?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, glm-math

I am trying to make a triangle and I'm using GLEW, GLFW and GLM as extensions of OpenGL.

Here's the code I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL 

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window; // (In the accompanying source code, this variable is global)
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // An array of 3 vectors which represents 3 vertices
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    // This will identify our vertex buffer
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    do {
        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );
        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
        glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
}
```

**Edit**

The code is not displaying the white triangle its just opens the window and shows empty black.
Also at first I added the code I messed around with, which is missing part of the code. However it still does not produce the white triangle.

Comment: Oh and it throws up an error about navpi.dll pdb file but I read that this does not matter.

Comment: What are you asking? It is not clear what you want to know.

Comment: Ah lol let me reedit

Comment: Doesn't OpenGL 3.3 mandate the use of shaders?  I don't see any in your code.

Comment: Hm shouldnt it just work and show white, shaders are for colouring right? I will try and add the shader to see if it shows.

Comment: Ah wait i might have different version of opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to use a shader for OpenGL 3.3?

**You need to use a shader or you *won't* see anything.** If you do see something then that is unspecified behavior. Which highly depend on each individual driver.

---

You could try fiddling with the clear color and clear the screen:

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The tutorial was able to get a white triangle on a black background. On my computer the opposite was the case.

The tutorial also points out:

> If you’re on lucky, you can see the result (don’t panic if you don’t)

So read the rest of the tutorial, it also includes a shader.

[image]